# How does control reach to AuthenticationEntryPoint

Tags: java, spring-security

I was just wondering how does the control of the execution reach the Authentication EntryPoint in spring security. I did not find anything in the Authentication Filters that transfers the control to the Entry point.

I have a custom Authentication Filter and Custom Authentication Provider. I need to redirect to a third party authentication server for authentication and this apps send me the authentication token that will authenticate the local app.

How an from where do i send the control to authentication Entry point.

Please do let me know if i am missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 2):

The best place to start is the [API docs for the interface](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/AuthenticationEntryPoint.html). This points you to the [`ExceptionTranslationFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/ExceptionTranslationFilter.html) which explains when the authentication entry point is invoked. Basically, it is used when someone is not authenticated and their request is rejected because they need to be.

If you have an external authentication server, you might want to look at the CAS implementation as a guide. Your filter should probably be checking the incoming request for a token and redirecting to the external server if it isn't present. In that case you might not need an `AuthenticationEntryPoint` at all, since no unauthenticated requests would get past your filter.

It's hard to give more specific information without knowing how your external authentication server works.